# Invalid column name 'EmailAddress' when using generic repository, but works fine with context

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Getting the mentioned error when trying to do a GetAll on accounts.  It works fine if I go directly to the dbcontext, but gives me the error if I try to work with the repo.  I have about 20 others that use just the generic repo and are working great.  Because I have additional actions for Accounts, I have created its own repository that implements the generic.  I also have several others that work like this and have no problem.  The problem is specific to the accounts.

Database of course does have the EmailAddress column, since I can return it if I use dbcontext from the controller instead of the repo.

Any help would be much appreciated.

AccountsController:

```
public class AccountsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly AccountRepository _repo;

    public AccountsController(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        _repo = new AccountRepository(context);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Account>>> GetAccount()
    {
        // return _context.Account.ToListAsync(); works fine if _context is defined
                    var accounts = await _repo.GetAll();
        if (accounts == null)
            return NoContent();

        return Ok(accounts); // Gives invalid column error
    }

    [HttpGet("getaccount")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Account>> GetCurrentAccount()
    {
        var account = await _repo.GetCurrentAccount(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
        if (account == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return account; // Works fine
    }
}
```

Account:

```
public partial class Account
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string RefId { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

IAccountRepository:

```
public interface IAccountRepository : IRepository<Account>
{
    Task<Account> GetCurrentAccount(string emailAddress);
}
```

AccountRepository:

```
public class AccountRepository : Repository<Account>, IAccountRepository
{
    private DatabaseContext _context;

    public AccountRepository(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<Account> GetCurrentAccount(string emailAddress)
    {
        var account = await _context.Account
            .Where(a => a.EmailAddress == emailAddress)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        return account; // this works just fine, and returns with EmailAddress
    }
}
```

IRepository (generic):

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll();
    Task<T> GetById(object id);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    Task<bool> Save();
}
```

Repository (generic):

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private DatabaseContext _context;

    public Repository()
    {
        _context = new DatabaseContext();
    }

    public Repository(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Add(T obj)
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Add(obj);
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll()
    {
        return await _context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<T> GetById(object id)
    {
        return await _context.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
    }

    public void Update(T obj)
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Update(obj);
    }

    public async Task<bool> Save()
    {
        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I should mention that EmailAddress was added to the database via EF migration.

Comment: Here `public AccountRepository(DatabaseContext context)`, shouldn't you pass the `context` to the base constructor? From the posted code looks like base repository methods use different context instance, although that doesn't explain the different behavior.